# /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18: no version information available

Tags: mysql, c++

I wrote a program in C++ (QtCreator) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which reads values from Web-API's (curl) and stores them in a MySQL Database (using the MySQL C-API). When I start the program on my Desktiop everything works fine, but when i put it on my ubuntu-12.04-i386-minimal vServer, it outputs "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18: no version information available" then starts running. 
How can I fix this? My Program also gets Segmentation faults sometimes, I think it's because of this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like library versions mismatch - you build on newer system (14.04) linking to one version of library and start it on a bit older (12.04), using different version of the library.